# How parcelable works and why data should be in sequence?

Tags: java, android

I am using Parcelable. Here, i have done some test code.

```
TestParcelable.java
--------------------
package com.example.parcelableexample;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class TestParcelable implements Parcelable {

    private String bName;
    private String aName;
    private int pTime;

    public String getbName() {
        return bName;
    }

    public void setbName(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public int getpTime() {
        return pTime;
    }

    public void setpTime(int pTime) {
        this.pTime = pTime;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<TestParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<TestParcelable>() {

        @Override
        public TestParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            TestParcelable test = new TestParcelable();
            test.bName = source.readString();
            test.aName = source.readString();
            test.pTime = source.readInt();
            return test;
        }

        @Override
        public TestParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestParcelable[size];
        }

    }; 

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {


        dest.writeString(bName);
        dest.writeInt(pTime);
        dest.writeString(aName);



    }

}

MainActivity.java
-------------------

package com.example.parcelableexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnPar;

    public  final static String PAR_KEY = "com.example.parcelableexample.par";  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnPar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btnPar.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }


    public void parcelableMethod() {
        TestParcelable testParcelable = new TestParcelable();
        testParcelable.setbName("TOC");
        testParcelable.setaName("Ullman");
        testParcelable.setpTime(0000);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ObjectP.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putParcelable(PAR_KEY, testParcelable);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == btnSer) {
            parcelableMethod();
    }
}
```

When i am changing the sequence of write in this method writeToParcel(), than it is taking some null value instead of actual value. Some please explain why we should maintain the sequence of read and write data in parcelable?

Answer (score 0):

I am not perfectly sure but according to my understanding both methods i.e. writeToParcel and createFromParcel are working like a pair, means you have to have same sequence in both of the methods.

Its working something like,

writeToParcel is generating a string in which its writing your first value i.e. bName(string value) than some seperator than pTime (int value) than again seperator and than aName (string value) while createFromParcel is converting from that string to object it is not getting the sequence as its expecting. Thats why it getting null value.

If you have to change sequence than you have to change on both ends.

note: above explanation is just for understanding , i am not truly aware of internal mechanism of these methods.